# Limit array checkboxes

Tags: jquery

If you want to prevent a user to mark more than, for example, 4 checkboxes, you can use:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=subculture]").click(function() {

    var bol = $("input[type=checkbox][name=subculture]:checked").length >= 4;     
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=subculture]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);

});
```

But if my checkboxes are an Array like:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="option1" id="attachments[29][subculture][]" name="attachments[29][subculture][]" />option1

<input type="checkbox" value="option2" id="attachments[29][subculture][]" name="attachments[29][subculture][]" />option2

<input type="checkbox" value="option3" id="attachments[29][subculture][]" name="attachments[29][subculture][]" />option3
```

...

How can I fix the above Jquery code to validate something like that?

where 29 is the ID of the actual post edited.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mvelaga/kKGcJ/1/), I hoe its useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to use double quotes with those types of selectors. Doing it that way will allow you to specify the names you want. See below or my jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/UNf65/):

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=\"attachments[29][subculture][]\"]").click(function() {
    var bol = $("input[type=checkbox][name=\"attachments[29][subculture][]\"]:checked").length >= 4;     
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=\"attachments[29][subculture][]\"]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);
});
```

The other option you have is to add a class to each input and then use that as the selector.

Comment: Thank you Drackir. But if the ID is passed in the query string like: ?attachment_id=29 how can I capture that variable. Thanks.

Comment: @José Pablo Orozco Marín: I'm not sure I understand completely. Can you not populate it with a server-side language like php or ASP.Net? Or is it loaded using AJAX?

Comment: nope, is wordpress, and the ID is passed by query string: attachment_id=29 where 29 is an attachment/post ID. And im using Jquery to validate those checkboxes, but I cdont know how to capture the query string with Jquery.

Comment: I think im going to try: http://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser  Thank you Drackir.